# How to prevent AutoMapper from overwriting existing values on destination object?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, automapper-10

I have the following entities and corresponding view models

```cs
public class TopEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public ICollection<BottomEntity> Bottoms { get; set; }
}

public class BottomEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int TopId { get; set; }
}

public class TopEntityViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public ICollection<BottomEntityViewModel> Bottoms { get; set; }
}

public class BottomEntityViewModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map an instance of type `TopEntityViewModel` to an instance of type `TopEntity` without overriding any value on `BottomEntity.TopId` that might already be there.

I've configured AutoMapper as follows:

```cs
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(exp =>
{
  exp.CreateMap<TopEntity, TopEntityViewModel>();

  exp.CreateMap<BottomEntity, BottomEntityViewModel>();

  exp.CreateMap<TopEntityViewModel, TopEntity>();

  exp.CreateMap<BottomEntityViewModel, BottomEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TopId, opts => opts.Ignore());
});
```

I've added `.ForMember(dest => dest.TopId, opts => opts.Ignore());` to ignore `BottomEntity.TopId` during mapping thinking that it should help preserve the existing value.

I'm mapping the instances like so:

```cs
mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            
var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

var topEntity = new TopEntity
{
  Id = 45,
  Bottoms = new List<BottomEntity>
  {
    new BottomEntity
    {
      Id = 56,
      TopId = 45
    },
    new BottomEntity
    {
      Id = 57,
      TopId = 45
    }
  }
};

var topEntityVm = new TopEntityViewModel
{
  Id = 45,
  Bottoms = new List<BottomEntityViewModel>
  {
    new BottomEntityViewModel
    {
      Id = 56,
    },
    new BottomEntityViewModel
    {
      Id = 57
    }
  }
};

            
var updatedTopEntity = mapper.Map(topEntityVm, topEntity);
```

When I access `updatedTopEntity.Bottoms[<whatever>].TopId` it's always set to 0.
If I update my definition of the property `BottomEntity.TopId` on the class to have a default value like `1000`, after mapping all my `updatedTopEntity.Bottoms[<whatever>].TopId` are set to that default value (`1000` in the example).
I've checked if the references returned from `mapper.Map` map the original references and they do.

How do I prevent AutoMapper from removing any existing values on the existing instances ?

I'm using AutoMapper 10.1.1 with .NET Core 5. [You can try a working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LR5auJ).

Comment: Did you also check if `Bottoms` is the same collection instance?

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AutoMapper` says this [in the documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#lists-and-arrays):

> When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.

[AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection), according to the documentation, does:

> Adds ability to map collections to existing collections without re-creating the collection object.
> Will Add/Update/Delete items from a preexisting collection object based on user defined equivalency between the collection's generic item type from the source collection and the destination collection.

After installing `AutoMapper.Collection` I've updated the AutoMapper configuration as follows:

```cs
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(exp =>
  {
    exp.AddCollectionMappers();
                
    exp.CreateMap<TopEntity, TopEntityViewModel>();

    exp.CreateMap<BottomEntity, BottomEntityViewModel>();

    exp.CreateMap<TopEntityViewModel, TopEntity>();

    exp.CreateMap<BottomEntityViewModel, BottomEntity>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.TopId, opts => opts.Ignore())
      .EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Id == dest.Id);
  });
```

The line `.EqualityComparison((src, dest) => src.Id == dest.Id);` adds an equality comparison that AutoMapper will use as follows:

- If Ids match, then AutoMapper will map BottomEntityViewModel to BottomEntity
- If BottomEntityViewModel exists and BottomEntity doesn't, then AutoMapper will add a new BottomEntity mapped from BottomEntityViewModel to the collection
- If BottomEntity exists and BottomEntityViewModel doesn't, then AutoMapper will remove BottomEntity from collection

This behavior of `AutoMapper.Collection` [is described here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection#adding-equivalency-between-two-classes)
Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tnaUjY

Thanks to [Lucian Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu) for pointing me to the correct direction